# Change text value to button

Tags: jquery, html-select, selected

I  have select option show list of countries with flags icons of each countries, and I use css to get flag icons.
like this

```
<form name="form" id="form">
    <table width="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
             <td wide="20"> 
                 <select class="custom" name="countriesFlag">
                     <option class="usa">USA</option>
                     <option class="italy">Italy</option>
                     <option class="france">France</option>
                     <option class="germany">Germany</option>
                 </select>
             </td>
</form>
```

when person selected value from the list and it will change and show the value text with icon in the button, but I want to show only flag icon not text in the button, how can I write that code in jquery or css that not to show text but only icon!

Comment: Sorry, but what button are you talking about?

Comment: With which part do you have a problem? Reading the `class` of the selected `option`? Or adding that class to a button? Plus, you options don't have any specific value…

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tips solution for hide text in css :

```
.theClassOfTagWhereHiddenText {
     text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Comment: WTF? How does that even relate to the question? A kind of description would be helpful here.

Comment: Many years coding... smell CSS newbee

Comment: The question is not a CSS question as in "How to hide text after an icon", but a JS question on how to transfer the selected value to the button…

Comment: WTF? How does that even relate to the question?  [...]

Comment: what im trying to say that in option menu button i want to hide the text but show icon... is works great with  text-indent: -9999px; thanks so much.

Comment: add+1 plz , for some reason [feela](http://stackoverflow.com/users/341201/feeela) add -1 ..

Comment: @jmercier Well, what this back-and-forth highlights is that your answer could use some explanation. It was flagged for the Low Quality Posts review queue because it's just a few lines of code with no description. I'm not casting a close vote, but other reviewers might.

Comment: @user3220804 If you feel that your question has been answered, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the hollow check mark to the left of the answer rather than posting a comment thanking the answerer. Once you have at least 15 rep, you can also upvote the accepted answer and any other answers you found useful. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: this site is to help users, including other people are the last resort, you have to read between the lines for them too .. but time consuming on this thread ..

Answer (score 1):

Right, jmercier is giving a really abbreviated answer, but isn't far off.
A (mostly) standard way of showing a background graphic, but not the text in an element is to set the background in css, and give that object a negative text indent, essentially pulling the text out of view (but leaving it in the html for screen readers and such). E.g.
HTML

```
<div id="usa">USA</div>
```

CSS

```
#usa{
     background-image('usa-flag.jpg');
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     overflow:hidden;
     height:20px;
     width:20px;
     text-indent:-9999px
}
```

The caveat is that forms and selectors really don't like styles, even a border will cause strange display in some browsers.  "Select" is especially touchy. So you can try text-indent, A Mohorev's answer brings up an interesting idea too, you could set the background color and the text color to be the same value.  Or some browsers even respect a text color of 'transparent.'
Another caveat is that mobile platforms more and more are using there own UI for forms and fieldsets, so for those cases, there really isn't anything you can do.